# Keras neural network "Function call stack: keras_scratch_graph"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to build a machine learning model using keras and I am getting below error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[1,1478] = 92260 is not in [0, 22000)
     [[node embedding_3/embedding_lookup (defined at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3-5.2.0\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_10071]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

code

```
filepath=".../weights-simple.hdf5"
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit([X_train], batch_size=32, y=to_categorical(y_train), verbose=1, validation_split=0.25, 
         shuffle=True, epochs=3, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

I even tried using below code, but I am still getting the error

```
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
```

Can you please help me with the issue

Comment: Can you provide a few more details on this issue, sample code snippet where the error is occurring would be great!